# How to install Warzone 2100 Cutscenes

Tags: games

I'm new to the Linux operating system in general, so I really don't know what I'm doing. I've downloaded the Warzone 2100 cutscenes from the main site, but I don't know how to install it into the game. Could someone perhaps give me some instructions on how to preform this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy that file into .warzone2100-3.1 (or whatever your version is). It's a hidden folder in your home directory. Then you just have to launch the game. If you can see the intro (an option in the main menu) then it means it worked.

Sources:

- readme here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/warzone2100/files/warzone2100/Videos/high-quality-en/
- figured that out just now :P